# Dev trying to attack me? Connection is private in localhost

Tags: google-chrome, security, localhost

Well. My developer just sent all code for my website and I was going to set it up at localhost and now it says:

Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Is this safe? What could he do possibly have done? Is he trying to attack me? Please help me. What can I do?

Comment: This is usually not a problem with the website-code but with the webserver-configuration -  so who did the SSL-set at your webserver on localhost? What webserver are you running?

Comment: I have not configured anything. All my other script have never got any error like this. I'm running XAMPP, not sure about version @piet.t